# Why can't I add a Dog Face (u+1f436) field to my object without using a String?

Tags: javascript, unicode

This:

```
var foo = {
  : true //Truely adorable
};
```

Gives me an Illegal Character error on Firefox and Chrome. However,

```
var foo = {
  '' : true
};
```

Works perfectly. Why?
(You can also answer for a wider set of Unicode characters, but I really want to know more about Dog)

Comment: Here's a great explanation of what's allowed and what's not: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: Because its not in a unicode range of allowed identifier characters. The latter example is just a string containing the character. See [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As the ECMAScript standard defines](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-names-and-keywords), valid identifiers must start with a Unicode code point with the Unicode property `ID_Start`.

[This is not the case](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F436) for the [poor dog](https://codepoints.net/U+1F436?lang=en). :(

You may use any of these code points as first character of your identifier:

http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:ID_Start=Yes:]

Comment: Okay I found the Hiragana (`ちえん`) but it's still 3 characters so meh. Update: One character! In traditional chinese : `狗` (U+72D7).

Comment: Try an [Egyptian hieroglyph](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf). Not sure if your IDE (or even your browser) will render them though.